# How does Swift implement ARC in property attributes?

Tags: swift

How does Swift implement ARC in property attributes?  For example, how do I make my String variable use copy instead of strong in Swift?

Comment: Apple's *Swift Programming Language* has whole [chapter](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) on ARC in Swift.

Comment: I recommend that you watch the intermediate Swift WWDC session as well. https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the `@NSCopying` attribute when you want the `copy` behaviour from Objective-C.

From the [Swift Book:](https://itun.es/us/jEUH0.l)

> Apply this attribute to a stored variable property of a class. This
>   attribute causes the property’s setter to be synthesized with a copy
>   of the property’s value—returned by the copyWithZone method—instead of
>   the value of the property itself. The type of the property must
>   conform to the NSCopying protocol.
>
> The NSCopying attribute behaves in a way similar to the Objective-C
>   copy property attribute.

However, in the specific case of `String` properties, it's not necessary to do so.

Strings are a value type in Swift. As such, when an existing `String` is assigned to a new variable, the variable actually stores a copy of the String, rather than a reference to the existing one.

> Swift’s String type is a value type. If you create a new String value,
>   that String value is copied when it is passed to a function or method,
>   or when it is assigned to a constant or variable. In each case, a new
>   copy of the existing String value is created, and the new copy is
>   passed or assigned, not the original version.

So, the `@NSCopying` attribute is to be used when you have properties of a reference type that you want to set using the copy behaviour.